# Why is it wrong for me to run the tests of a specific directory with cypress?

Tags: javascript, bdd, cypress

I am trying to run some specific tests within a directory, using cypress the command that I try to execute is:

```
node_modules\.bin\cypress run --spec 'cypress\integration\tests\default.spec.js'
```

I have also tried with:

```
node_modules\.bin\cypress run --spec 'cypress\integration\tests\*.spec.js'
```

Or:

```
node_modules\.bin\cypress run --spec 'cypress\integration\tests\**'
```

The directory and the files exist, I tried to keep the absolute path to those files but it does not work either. Try changing the configuration of the integration directory in the cypress.json, at the end I have this file:

**cypress.json**

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost/",
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "integrationFolder": "./cypress/integration/",
  "testFiles": "**.spec.js"
}
```

This is the message's error: Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files matching this glob pattern:

'cypress\integration\tests\default.spec.js'

Comment: What if you try with forward slashes, as [the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run-spec-lt-spec-gt) show?

Comment: Why are you trying to run things from `node_modules` instead of using `npx` (for running local dependency CLI tools) or just `cypress` in an npm script? `"cypress": "cypress run"` and presto, `npm run cypress` runs cypress.

Comment: In Azure, forward slashes were the problem.  The fix (at least when running on windows) took a certain script: https://www.intheclouds.blog/2019/01/30/running-cypress-tests-in-azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but I just came across this issue.

I solved it by using (=) `--spec=cypress/integration/[path]`, it can't detect if I'm using quotes, `--spec 'cypress/integration/[path]'`.