# Unable to run tests in a specific location

Tags: cypress

I have mocked integration tests in the default `/cypress/integration` directory and have end-to-end tests in `/cypress/e2e`.  I'm attempting to add a script to my package.json file which will specifically run the E2E tests.

I have the following scripts defined:

```
  "scripts": {
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "test:e2e": "npx cypress run --spec \"cypress/e2e/**/*.spec.ts\"",
  }
```

When I do a `npm run test:e2e`, I see the following:

> npx cypress run --spec "cypress/e2e/**/*.spec.ts"
>
> Can't run because no spec files were found.
>
> We searched for any files matching this glob pattern:
>
> cypress\e2e***.spec.ts
> I've also tried running a specific test in the command line using the following two commands with the same unsuccessful result:

`npx cypress run --spec "cypress\e2e\enterprise\taxpayer.spec.ts"`

`npm run cy:run -- --spec "cypress\e2e\enterprise\taxpayer.spec.ts"`

The spec file itself starts with a `describe()` function block.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324050/why-is-it-wrong-for-me-to-run-the-tests-of-a-specific-directory-with-cypress) answer says you can use an equals sign, but that's also not working for me.

**Any idea why Cypress is not recognizing my test?**

Answer (score 0):

Updating your spec file folder should be done via `cypress.json` (this sits outside your `cypress` folder and inside the root directory). You need to include this:

```
"integrationFolder": "./cypress/e2e"
```

Hence, the CLI should be:

```
npx cypress run --spec "cypress/e2e/enterprise/taxpayer.spec.ts"
```

Other configuration (e.g. screenshot folder, etc.) can be found here:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Folders-Files

Comment: That's the default folder location setting. I'm familiar with that. You should be able to run any spec file(s) at any time, though, regardless of if it's in the defined spec folder, no?

Comment: Aha. Sorry misunderstood it a bit. Try using this `"integrationFolder": "./"` instead in the `cypress.json`. If it works, I will update my answer.